# Why top doesn't list my application as real-time?

Tags: top, scheduling, c++, priority

I am trying to learn the scheduling policy on Linux with a small `C++` application. The same should be valid for `C`. I am changing the priority of my app using the code below:

```
sched_param tParam;
sched_getparam(0, &tParam);                                             
tParam.sched_priority   = 20;
sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_RR, &tParam);
```

I was expecting my app to be shown as real-time, `rt`, when I run `top` but it is not. This is what I get:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2652 root      -21   0  145452  63460  11444 R  1.3  1.6   0:02.08 myRealTimeApp
```

a negative `PR` value. But when I run `chrt -p 2652` I get:

```
pid 2652's current scheduling policy: SCHED_RR
pid 2652's current scheduling priority: 20
```

which makes sense.

`top` does not list my app as `rt` unless I increase the priority level to `99`.

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2770 root      rt   0  145452  63460  11444 S  1.0  1.6   0:01.93 myRealTimeApp
```

My questions are:

- Why `top` doesn't consider my app as real-time unless the priority is set to `99`?
- Why `top` shows the priority level as a negative number while it is not.
- What are the risks if I set the priority to `99`?

Answer (score 0):

If your process takes very few resources, there is no cause of worry and you could make it run in real time, but it won't really make much of a difference.  The risks and problems occur when the process in question overloads the CPU and prevents essential tasks from doing their work.

There is usually no need to do more than a `renice -20` (priority 0) since it will be prioritized over any unimportant processes except those that you reniced yourself.

When you set the priority to `-21` by defining it in RT, you are actually overrunning important processes including (but not limited to) window managers, login processes, and even network management.  Fortunately, because of what you consider a flaw, the system will still continue to process important tasks (albeit less efficiently) even if the process is maxing out on CPU.

Should you decide that your process is so important that it needs to be really considered in real time and it takes all the CPU power, than all other non real time processes will come to an halt.  This is a guaranteed recipe for disaster as nothing other than what the system already put in real time will operate and many operations will fail or become unreliable (mainly disk and network access).  Even swap control may be affected, causing side-effects in the system's capability in managing available memory.

It is usually more reasonable to give a process the worse priority at which it can properly operate in order to prevent any of the aforementioned issues.

Note that some systems are designed to run in real time but that implies a massive redesign of all priorities and running processes to prevent any undesired results.